# Counting bounded integer solutions to $\sum_ia_ix_i\leqq n$

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, diophantine-equations, integer-partitions, faq

I want to find the number of nonnegative integer solutions to
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=22$$
which is also the number of *combinations with replacement* of $22$ items in $4$ types.

How do I apply [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) for this? What if there is an inequality or the lower bounds on the $x_i$ are not zero?

More generally, what do I use if the $x_i$ are multiplied by integer constants, such as in this equation?
$$3x_1+2x_2+x_3+x_4=47$$

Comment: Do the $x_i$ need to be all positive, or just non-negative?

Comment: Sorry, yes they are natural numbers

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Yes, the [Stars-and-Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29) approach works great here, but you should know that there are two "versions" of the *Stars-and-Bars* approach. In both versions, we look for the number of distinct integer solutions to an equation such as yours.

In the first version, we require that every $x_i$ must be a positive integer.

In the second version, the restriction eases to include all *non-negative $x_i$*.

So, for example in your case, $x_1= 0, x_2=9, x_3=0, x_4=13$ would be one distinct solution in the second version, but would not be a solution in the first version.

**I. positive integers $x_i$**

For any pair of positive integers n and k, the number of distinct k-tuples of **positive integers** whose sum is $n$ is given by the binomial coefficient $${n - 1\choose k-1}.$$

In your case, $k = 4, n=22$. So the number of distinct solutions $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ where the $x_i \in \mathbb Z, x_i>0$ is given by $$\binom{22-1}{4-1} = \binom{21}{3} = \frac{21!}{3!18!} = 1330$$

---

**II. non-negative integers $x_i$**

For any pair of natural numbers n and k, the number of distinct k-tuples of **non-negative integers** (which includes the possibility that one or more of the $x_i$ are zero) whose sum is $n$ is given by the binomial coefficient $$\binom{n + k - 1}{n} = \binom{n+k-1}{k-1}.$$

In your problem, $k = 4, n = 22.$  Here, the distinct solutions $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)$ will include those from $I.$, but also allows 4-tuples in which one or more of the $x_i$ are zero: $x_i \in \mathbb Z, x_i\geq 0$.

$$\binom{22 + 4 -1}{22} = \binom{25}{22} = \dfrac{25!}{22!3!} = 2300$$

Comment: Could you help me with my newer stars and bars problem? Noone has seen it

Comment: Isn't the formula (n+k-1) choose k and not choose n? The equivalent would be (n+k-1) choose (n+k-1-k = n-1)?

Comment: See how I've defined n, k. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)

Comment: @inggumnator No, sorry. I think you're mixing up $n$ and $k$. The desired sum is $n$; $k$ is the number of $x_i$ (variables) whose sum is $n$.  Go to the link I've posted above to re-educate yourself.  Note that $$\binom{n+k-1}{n} = \binom{n+l -1}{k-1}$$

Comment: How did you decide what is $n$ and what is $k$?

Answer (score 19):

**The star method:** consider 22 balls and 3 separations (because you have 4 boxes). I denote $*$ for the balls and $\Big |$ for the separation. Then it's the number of permutation of:

$$\left\{\underbrace{*\ *\ \cdots *\ }_{22\ balls}\Big|\hspace{0.5cm}\Big|\hspace{0.5cm} \Big|\hspace{0.5cm}\right\}$$

There is $25!$ permutations but the permutation of the balls together and the permutations of the separation together doesn't give a new combinaison, so you have to divide $25!$ by $3!22!$ and it gives
$$\frac{25!}{3!22!}=\binom{25}{3}$$ different solutions.

Comment: To me, $\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,3,...\}$ and so $0\in\mathbb N$. If $0$ wouldn't be included, he would write $x_i\in\mathbb N^*$.

Comment: @idm Did you know how to solve my newest question? It is a continuation of this one

Comment: What is the new question ? I don't see it.

Comment: @idm http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911618/how-to-convert-a-problem-to-a-stars-and-bars-problem

Comment: can you extend this answer for N* using same logic?

Answer (score 7):

> How to use the stars and bars method?

For $x_i\ (i=1,2,3,4)\in\mathbb N$, we have 
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=22\iff (x_1-1)+(x_2-1)+(x_3-1)+(x_4-1)=18.$$

Here, note that $x_i-1\ (i=1,2,3,4)$ are *non-negative integers*.

Choosing $4-1=3$ places (for bars) from $18+(4-1)$ places (for bars and stars) leads the answer is $\binom{18+(4-1)}{4-1}=\binom{21}{3}=1330.$

Comment: Why does your answer differ to that of idm?

Comment: @user1341841914820412812412: If I'm note mistaken, idm thinks that $x_i$ are non-negative integers.

Comment: So he has permitted $0$, and you have not?

Comment: @user1341841914820412812412: Yes, exactly.

Comment: That's fine, having the contrast is actually quite nice.

Answer (score 3):

### Inequalities

To count nonnegative integer solutions of
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4\le22$$
add a *slack variable* $x_5$ to the left-hand side representing the gap between $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4$ and $22$, which is by definition nonnegative:
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=22$$
Stars and bars then gives $\binom{22+4}4=14950$ solutions.

### General bounds

To count integer solutions of
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=22$$
with $-2\le x_1\le7$ and all other $x_i$ bounds unchanged from the basic problem, first add $2$ to both sides and set $y=x_1+2$ with $0\le y\le9$:
$$y+x_2+x_3+x_4=24$$
Without $y$'s upper bound, stars and bars gives $\binom{24+3}3=2925$ solutions. We need to remove solutions with $y\ge10$; we count these unwanted solutions like the lower bound case, by defining another nonnegative integer variable $z=y-10$ and simplifying:
$$z+x_2+x_3+x_4=14$$
There are $\binom{14+3}3=680$ solutions to this, so the final answer is $2925-680=2245$.

Multiple nonzero lower bounds can be handled independently. Multiple upper bounds need to be handled using inclusion–exclusion. In particular, the number of ways $n$ ordered dice with faces from $0$ to $k-1$ can sum to $b$ is
$$\sum_{i=0}^n(-1)^i\binom ni\binom{b-ki+n-1}{n-1}$$

---

### Generating functions

Both of the above generalisations are themselves special cases of the generating function method, where the number of solutions to $\sum_ia_ix_i=n$ is found as the $x^n$ coefficient of a polynomial or power series whose factors encode information about a corresponding monomial.

A monomial $a_ix_i$ where $0\le p\le x_i\le q$ and $a_i$ is a constant positive integer corresponds to the factor
$$\sum_{k=p}^q(x^{a_i})^k=(x^{a_i})^p\frac{1-(x^{a_i})^{q-p+1}}{1-x^{a_i}}$$
where $x^{q-p+1}$ disappears if $q=\infty$. For example, the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $3x_1+2x_2+x_3+x_4=47$ is the $x^{47}$ coefficient of
$$\frac1{(1-x^3)(1-x^2)(1-x)^2}$$
which is $3572$.

**Modular** considerations may help to simplify such a problem. The number of nonnegative integer solutions to $x_1+5x_2+10x_3+25x_4+50x_5+100x_6=147$ equals the number of nonnegative integer solutions to $x_2+2x_3+5x_4+10x_5+20x_6\le29$, because $x_1$ must be of the form $5k+2$, because all other multipliers are divisible by $5$.

Comment: [+1] Interesting.

Comment: I appreciate the idea of turning this question into an abstract duplicate for all stars-and-bars question, BUT I think you made it a little _too_ general. I think that this question should only address counting $x_1+\dots+x_k=n$, with lower limits $x_i\ge b_i$. The other part of the question, counting $a_1x_1+\dots+a_kx_k=n$, could be handled in a separate question, like [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4770544/stars-and-bars-with-coefficients-on-variables#4770544). The two versions are so different, that it is awkward to have them in the same place. Do you disagree?

Comment: [Generating Functions] How were you able to compute the coefficient of $x^{47}$ in $\frac{1}{(1−x^3)(1−x^2)(1−x)^2}$?

Answer (score 2):

My answer specifically deals with the last question, of counting nonnegative integer solutions to
$$
a_1x_1+\dots+a_kx_k=n,\\
x_i\in\mathbb Z_{\ge 0},\quad i\in \{1,\dots,k\}
$$
Let $h_n$ be the number of solutions to the above (the dependence on $k,a_1,\dots,a_k$ is suppressed to simplify notation). We can give an exact expression for $h_n$ using generating functions:
$$
h_n=[t^{n}]\frac{1}{(1-t^{a_1})(1-t^{a_2})\cdots (1-t^{a_k})}
$$
Here. $[t^n] f(t)$ means the coefficient of $t^c$ when $f$ is expanded as a power series centered at $t=0$. To see why this works, note that $(1-t^{a_i})^{-1}=\sum_{x_i=0}^\infty t^{a_ix_i}$, so
$$
\prod_{i=1}^k (1-t^{a_i})^{-1}
=\sum_{x_1=0}^\infty\sum_{x_2=0}^\infty \cdots \sum_{x_k=0}^\infty t^{a_1x_1+\dots+a_kx_k}
$$
This means there is a contribution to $t^n$ for each way to write $n$ as $a_1x_1+\dots+a_kx_k$.

This gives a method to compute $h_n$ using a computer algebra system. Here is a piece of Mathematica code which computes $h_n$:

```
CoinGeneratingFunction[t_, CoinList_] := 
    1 / Product[(1 - t ^ CoinList[[i]]), {i, 1, Length[CoinList]}]
NumWaysMakeChange[TargetAmount_, CoinList_] := 
    SeriesCoefficient[ CoinGeneratingFunction[t, CoinList], {t, 0, TargetAmount}]

TargetAmount = 1000;
CoinList = List[2,3,6,8];

Print["There are ", NumWaysMakeChange[TargetAmount , CoinList], 
    " ways to make change for ", TargetAmount, 
    " using coins with values ", CoinList, "."]
```

See also my [question on computer science stack exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/103531/computing-number-of-ways-to-make-change) for more methods to compute $h_n$.

Thanks to [Schur's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_theorem#Combinatorics), we have a simple asymptotic expression for the number of solutions.

> **Schur's Theorem**: As $n\to\infty$, $$h_n= \frac{n^{k-1}}{(k-1)!(a_1\cdot a_2 \cdots a_k)}(1+o(1)).$$