# How to calculate the $k$-dimension of a subspace of a polynomial ring?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Let $k$ be an infinite field and $R:=k[x_1,...,x_n]$ the polynomial ring in $n$ indeterminates.

Why is the $k$-dimension of $U$ given by $\begin{pmatrix} n+m-1 \\ m\end{pmatrix}$, when $U$ is the subspace of $R$ defined by the $k$-span of those polynomials which are homogeneous of degree $m$ ?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hint: How many $n$-tuples $\left(r_1,r_2,\ldots,r_n\right)$ of nonnegative integers are there such that $r_1+r_2+\ldots+r_n=m$?

Comment: It's a [stars-and-bars](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910809/how-to-use-stars-and-barscombinatorics) computation.