# How do I calculate the number of unique permutations in a list with repeated elements?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I know that I can get the number of permutations of items in a list *without repetition* using

```
(n!)
```

How would I calculate the number of unique permutations when a given number of elements in `n` are repeated.

For example

ABCABD

I want the number of unique permutations of those 6 letters (using all 6 letters).

Comment: Funny, I just made a [code golf challenge](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/78399/permutations-with-indistinguishable-items) with this exact premise!

Comment: @qwr Someone asked about it on stackoverflow, but they were trying to brute force it and ran out of memory.  I thought surely there would be a question on *math* I could forward them to, but I couldn't find one.

Comment: How many are there for $AABB$?

Comment: Searching questions tagged `permutations` with keyword `repetition` will find many other related posts.  The `Mississippi` problem is something of a classic.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a specific formula for such problems:

Permute all elements, and remove permutations of elements that are identical, viz.

$\dfrac{6!}{2!2!}$

Answer (score -2):

Do you want the number of combinations of a fixed size? Or all sizes up to 6? If your problem is not too big, you can compute the number of combinations of each size separately and then add them up.

Also, do you care about order? For example, are AAB and ABA considered unique combinations? If these are not considered unique, consider trying stars-and-bars: [How to use stars and bars (combinatorics)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910809/how-to-use-stars-and-bars-combinatorics)

Comment: Sorry, I just updated my question.  I want permutations, not combinations.

Comment: the question asks about permutations, not combinations