# answer verification, permutations (ways to make n words out of m letters)

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-theorem

> How many ways are there to make different words (not necessarily meaningful) by changing order of letters in the word $b_1b_1...b_1b_2b_2...b_2...b_mb_m...b_m$, where $b_1$ appears $k_1$ times, $b_2$ appears $k_2$ times, ... , $b_m$ appears $k_m$ times.

My answer is $$\sum_{k_1+k_2+...+k_m = n \\ 0\leq k_i \leq n}\quad\Large\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!...k_m!}b_1^{k_1}b_2^{k_2}...b_m^{k_m}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Try out some small example to test your formula, with say one **a**, two **b's**, three **c's**

Comment: @trueblueanil would the answer be 60?

Comment: What does it mean to raise $b_1$ to some power?

Comment: If all the numbers would have been distinct, you would have $n!$ ways. If you make 4 of them the same, you can permute the 4 by fixing the others in $4!$ ways, so you're counting every case $4!$ times. So, there would be $n!/4!$ ways. Try to extend this to more groups of the same thing

Comment: @DavidP It means permutations of $b_1$ identical letters? So for k=3, $b_1^k$ would be ways to make 3 letter words out of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$, so 3*2*1 = 3!

Comment: @trueblueanil Isn't that what the question is asking?

Comment: I have written an answer to point out a possible source of your confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer of $60$ corresponds to $\large\frac{6!}{1!2!3!}$, the first part of your formula, which represents the number of permutations of a $n$ letter word with $k_1$ of the first kind, $k_2$ of the second kind,.... $\Sigma k_i = n$

This represents the multinomial **coefficient**

What you have possibly mixed it up with is the Multinomial **Theorem**, which states

If events $E_1, E_2, ... E_k$ can occur with probabilities $p_1, p_2, ... p_k$ respectively, then the probability that events $E_1, E_2, ... E_k$ will occur $X_1, X_2, ... X_k$ times respectively is

$$\Large\frac{N!}{X_1!X_2! ... X_k!}p_1^{X_1}p_2^{X_2}... p_k^{X_k}$$

where $X_1 + X_2 + ... X_k = N$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So the answer to the original question would just be $$\sum_{k_1+k_2+...+k_m = n \\ 0\leq k_i \leq n}\quad\Large\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!...k_m!}$$ ?

Comment: Yea, just the **multinomial coefficient**

Comment: So we only have one term, $\quad\Large\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!...k_m!}$ ? No summing up?

Comment: Or does multinomial coefficient include the sigma?

Comment: Actually, the formula should be written as $\large\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!...k_m!},\;{k_1+k_2+...+k_m = n;\; 0\leq k_i \leq n}$

Comment: Or if you insist on a sigma sign, $\large\frac{n!}{k_1!k_2!...k_m!},\;{ 0\leq k_i \leq n;\;\; \Sigma k_1 = n}$

Comment: Thank you! That was huge help.

Comment: Glad to be of help !\;\; :)

Comment: You might also like to see a simpler treatment of the problem https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1759845/how-do-i-calculate-the-number-of-unique-permutations-in-a-list-with-repeated-ele/1759860#1759860