# Number of strings that are made of $3$ 'a', $1$ 'b', $2$ 'c' and $2$ 'd' such that $aaa$ does not appear

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinatorics-on-words

> Number of strings that are made of $3$ 'a', $1$ 'b', $2$ 'c' and $2$ 'd' such that $aaa$ does not appear

---

I tried to first place the other letters such that $bccdd$ then we will have gaps ${\_b\_ c\_ c\_d \_d\_}$ for that we have $1!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!$ I thought to multiply by ${8 \choose 1}\cdot 1! \cdot {7 \choose 2} \cdot 2! \cdot {5 \choose 2 } \cdot 2!$ because of the total number of letters we have
but that is already wrong as the correct answer should be $1500$ and this is beyond $1500$

I got stuck here how do I continue after placing the letters, how to place the "a" i thoguht about needing two cases , one for a single "a" and one for "aa"?
thanks for any tips and help!

Comment: Arrange $bccdd$, obtain $6$ gaps.  Count the unrestricted ways to put $3$ identical objects in those gaps.  Subtract off the cases where all three go in the same gap.

Comment: See my answer for the requested alternative approaches, which includes a rehabilitation of your approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments following true blue anil's answer, this response details methods of attack that are **inferior** to the method taken by true blue anil.

First of all, just to sanity check true blue anil's method:

- First, you ignore the constraint against the $~3~$ A's together:
  $\displaystyle \frac{8!}{(3!) \times (1!) \times (2!) \times (2!)} = 1680.$
- Then you consider the number of ways of violating the constraint against the $~3~$ A's together:
  As indicated in the answer of true blue anil, you construe the $~3~$ A's as being **fused** into one unit, so now you have $6$ units to distribute.
  $\displaystyle \frac{6!}{(1!) \times (1!) \times (2!) \times (2!)} = 180.$
- Then, you perform the deduction:
  $1680 - 180 = 1500.$

---

First, I am going to critique your method.  Then, I will show an alternative method of attack that is inferior to true blue anil's method.

$\underline{\text{Critique of Your Method}}$

This is the method that you started.

> I tried to first place the other letters such that $bccdd$ then we will have gaps ${\_b\_ c\_ c\_d \_d\_}$ for that we have $1!\cdot 2!\cdot 2!$ I thought to multiply by ${8 \choose 1}\cdot 1! \cdot {7 \choose 2} \cdot 2! \cdot {5 \choose 2 } \cdot 2!$

This approach has two problems:

- Instead of $\displaystyle {8 \choose 1}\color{red}{\times 1!} \times {7 \choose 2} \color{red}{\times 2!} \times {5 \choose 2 } \color{red}{\times 2!}$ 
  Your preliminary calculation should be :
  $\displaystyle {8 \choose 1} \times {7 \choose 2} \times {5 \choose 2 }  = 1680.$ 
  The reason is that the $~2~$ C's are indistinguishable from each other.  Labeling these letters as C-1 and C-2, having C-1 precede C-2 is the same as having C-2 precede C-1.  Similarly, the $~2~$ D's are indistinguishable from each other.
- With the correction in place, and the preliminary computation at $1680$, the approach fails to consider that you are **not allowed** to have the $~5~$ characters other than an A be positioned so that they create a gap of three consecutive unused positions.
  This is why the correction to your preliminary computation yields the same answer as the preliminary calculation of true blue anil, $~1680.$

To rehabilitate your method, you would then need to deduct the number of ways of placing the $~5~$ characters other than an A so that they create a gap of three consecutive unused positions.

There are $~6~$ potential starting positions for the gap of three consecutive unused positions, since this gap can begin anywhere between positions $~1~$ through $~6~$ inclusive.

For each of the $~6~$ placements of the gap of three consecutive unused positions, the number of ways of placing the $~5~$ letters other than an A in the $~5~$ remaining positions is:

$\displaystyle \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{2} = \frac{5!}{(1!) \times (2!) \times (2!)} = 30.$

Then, the number of sequences that need to be deducted is $~6 \times 30 = 180.$

So, you arrive at the final answer of $~1680 - (6 \times 30) = 1500.$

---

$\underline{\text{Alternative Method}}$

I am going to use a *Stars and Bars* approach.  For Stars and Bars theory, see
[this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and
[this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

The $~3~$ A's need to be positioned so that they are not all together.  Consider the following illustration of placing the $~3~$ A's:

```
 _A_A_A_
```

That is, the $~3~$ A's (potentially) create $~4~$ regions; before the first A, and after each of the $~3~$ A's.

Consider the number of solutions to the following problem:

- $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 5.$
- $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Per Stars and Bars theory, the above problem has 
$\displaystyle \binom{5+[4-1]}{4-1} = \binom{8}{3} = 56~$ solutions.

The variables $~x_1, \cdots, x_4~$ represent the size of the respective regions.  The only way of violating the constraint against all three A's being together is if $~x_2~$ and  $~x_3~$ are **both** equal to $0$.

This corresponds to the number of solutions to the following problem:

- $x_1 + 0 + 0 + x_4 = 5.$
- $x_1, x_4 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$

Per Stars and Bars theory, the above problem has 
$\displaystyle \binom{5+[2-1]}{2-1} = \binom{6}{1} = 6~$ solutions.

Therefore, the total number of ways of placing the $~3~$ A's so that they are not all together is $56 - 6 = 50.$

As discussed in the previous section, for each such satisfying placement of the $~3~$ A's, the number of ways of placing the remaining letters is 
$\displaystyle \binom{5}{1} \times \binom{4}{2} \times \binom{2}{2} = \frac{5!}{(1!) \times (2!) \times (2!)} = 30.$

Therefore, the total number of satisfying sequences is

$$(56 - 6) \times 30 = 1500.$$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**

You can atart in the way that you did, but a simpler way is:

- Count total permutations of all $8$ letters
- Subtract permutations where $\boxed{AAA}$ is treated as one letter in the now $6$ "letters"

Comment: is it $8 \choose 3$ $\cdot $ $5\choose 2$ $\cdot$ $3 \choose 2$ $\cdot$ $1 \choose 1$ for all permutations?

Comment: Yes, but why not simply write it as $\Large\frac{8!}{3!2!2!1!}$

Comment: I am trying to solve in both ways but I seem to get a different answer all the time , can you provide another hint on this way and the way I started please?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1759845/how-do-i-calculate-the-number-of-unique-permutations-in-a-list-with-repeated-ele/1759860#1759860 for permutations with repeating letters, and solve it the way I have suggested. Then if "your" way gets a different answer, I'll look at it.

Comment: @Adamrk Per true blue anil's last comment, if you do get a *different answer*, first, add an **Addendum** to your posting, where you **very carefully, in a very detailed manner**, show your work.  **Then**, leave another comment following this answer.  Since the comment will be following this answer, true blue anil will automatically be flagged.

Comment: @user2661923 I managed to get the correct answer using anil's method but the way I started it is just not working because I do not know how to , thanks for you help! if you would like to give me an explanation to the other way it would be very helpful if not then also thank you again!
I usually put very detailed approaches to my questions but when I do not know what to do then there is nothing much to explain tbh

Comment: @Adamrk True blue anil's approach is definitely best, for this problem.  I have a doctor's appt right now.  However, later today, I will provide a separate answer that attacks the problem with the inferior method.  After I finish my answer, I will leave you a notification comment.

Comment: @user2661923 Thank you much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The method described by true blue anil is optimal.

Let's correct your attempt.  You wish to first arrange the five letters $b, c, c, d, d$.  There are $5$ ways to place the $b$, which leaves $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to place the two $c$s.  The two $d$s must be placed in the remaining two positions.  Hence, there are $\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{2}$ such arrangements.  Arranging the letters $b, c, c, d, d$ creates six spaces in which to place the three $a$s.
$$\square L_1 \square L_2 \square L_3 \square L_4 \square L_5 \square$$
To ensure that we do not place all three $a$s consecutively, we must either choose three of these six spaces in which to place an $a$ so that no two $a$s are consecutive, which can be done in $\binom{6}{3}$ ways, or choose one of these six spaces in which to place the block $aa$ and one of the five remaining spaces in which to place the remaining $a$ to ensure that exactly two of the three $a$s are consecutive, which can be done in $\binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1}$ ways.  Hence, the number of arrangements of $a, a, a, b, c, c, d, d$ in which not all three $a$s are consecutive is
$$\binom{5}{1}\binom{4}{2}\left[\binom{6}{3} + \binom{6}{1}\binom{5}{1}\right]$$