# How many solutions are there to $x+y+z=n$? Need help understanding the answer.

Tags: combinatorics

I need some help. I do not understand how to get the answer (solution) to this question. I could not solve it, neither did it help when I saw the answer. This is a question from the chapter combinatorics from my textbook. Should be noted that my textbook has not be explaining anything that resembles this kinds of questions. So I am stuck. I would appreciate some insights. Thanks.

**The question:**

Let $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$. How many solutions are there to the equation: $$x+y+z=n$$ such that $x,y,z \in \mathbb{N}$?

**The answer:**

> $\frac{1}{2}(n^{2} + 3n + 2)$

How did they arrive at this answer?

Comment: You may want to check [Stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). You could also check [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910809/how-to-use-stars-and-bars-combinatorics) post.

Comment: This has been asked many times, please perform a search of *stars and bars*.

Comment: I am not supposed to solve this using _Stars and bars_ because my textbook has not talked about that.

Comment: @notmyrealname What kind of crappy textbook asks you to do exercises without explaining them?

Comment: @StubbornAtom Is it possible to solve without using Stars and bars, because my textbook has not talked about that technique at all? So how do you solve it without it?

Comment: @Jam It is actually a quite good book.

Comment: Maybe your book has not used the term explicitly, but has used the combinatorial technique.

Comment: @notmyrealname It's not some advanced tecnhique. All you need is some basic logic and combinatorics.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Nope the only things it has brought up are the definitions of permutation, combination and the binomial theorem. Then you are asked this question....

Comment: Well the problem *is* concerned with permutation and combination. If no example was shown in the book then it probably wants you to have this knowledge beforehand (don't know why).

Comment: @StubbornAtom I look at the Bars and stars but I could not use that to arrive at $\frac{1}{2}(n^{2} + 3n + 2)$

Comment: Anyone who can solve this using the bars and stars technique? It seems that all the answers are given as the number of possible configurations, say $250$ or $4824$ et cetera. Not as an expression like $\frac{1}{2}(n^{2} + 3n + 2)$ I tried but got $\frac{1}{2}(n^3-6n^2 + 11n - 6)$ which is wrong.

Comment: Applying the formula we get $\binom{n+2}{2}=\frac{n^2+3n+2}{2}$

Comment: @StubbornAtom Thank you. I used $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$. I should instead use $\binom{n+1}{k-1}$?

Comment: The answer you have provided is for non-negative $x,y,z$. For just finding out the answer remember that $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ is the number of *non-negative* integral solutions of $x_1+x_2+...+x_k=n$, and $\binom{n-1}{k-1}$ is the number of *positive* integral solutions of the same equation.

Answer (score 0):

**Note that zero should be included**

> Considering $$z(x,y) = n-x-y$$
>
> where $x,y\in \mathbb{N}\cup \{ 0 \}$ and $x+y\leq n$

The number of elements in the domain:

\begin{align*}
  \sum_{x=0}^{n} \sum_{y=0}^{n-x} 1 &=
  \sum_{x=0}^{n} (n-x+1) \\ &=
  (n+1)\times \frac{(n+1)+1}{2} \\ &=
  \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}
\end{align*}