# Find the number of combinations such that sum of N numbers equals to M

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, factorial

Here is the problem:

Let M (the sum) be 10 and N (the number of numbers) be 4.

Some possible combinations are are (10, 0, 0, 0), (5, 3, 2, 0), (8, 1, 1, 0), (8, 2, 0, 0), (6, 2, 1, 1), etc.

How do I calculate the number of possible combinations?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you know what partitions are?

Comment: This is a standard application of a [stars-and-bars computation](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910809/how-to-use-stars-and-bars-combinatorics).

Comment: Just had a quick read about it from: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)#Partition_function, but I am unsure how to apply the formula

Comment: The link I gave you is to a previous Question at Math.SE about how to apply its logic.

Comment: @SakethMalyala:  You ask about (integer) partitions, in which the order of summands is ignored, but I have interpreted the problem as concerning [compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)), in which order of summands matters.  We may get some clarification from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

As covered in the previous Question as well as the Wikipedia article, the number of such summations (order is important, so [weak compositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)) rather than partitions) is $\binom{M+N-1}{N-1}$.

---

The example $M=10$ and $N=4$ of the OP then yields $\binom{13}{3} = 286$.

If instead we wanted to disregard order of summands, this is an overcount (since $6 + 1 + 1 + 0 = 0 + 1 + 1 + 6$, etc.).  The number of [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $10$ with *at most* $4$ parts (zeros omitted, or padded out with zeros to give exactly four summands) is only $23$.

One can ask [the Maxima Online Algebra Calculator](http://maxima-online.org/) to find this with the command:

```
length(integer_partitions(10,4));
```