# Integral solutions involving modulus

Tags: combinatorics

Can someone help with these kind of questions

Find the number of integral solution of the following equation:

$$|x|+|y|+|z|=5$$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRLp9.jpg

Comment: where can i plot the integer solutions?

Comment: see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

$x$ and $y$ can take any the integer values $0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4,\pm5$; they can't take any other values (why not?). The value of $|z|$ is then determined by those of $x$ and $y$; as $z$ also must be one of the integer values listed, you must have $|x|+|y|\le5$. If $|x|+|y|=5$, then $z=0$, otherwise $z$ has two values, one positive and one negative.

Using these hints, can you make a start?

Answer (score 0):

This is an application of the stars-and-bars theorem.

Check this out : [How to use stars and bars (combinatorics)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910809/how-to-use-stars-and-bars-combinatorics)

In this case, your problem is asking for the number of non-negative integral solutions to the equation.

$$
x+y+z=5
$$
The answer will be $\binom{5+3-1}{5}=21$