# Arrangement for run of A and B

Tags: probability

[image]

I found a similiar [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910809/how-to-use-stars-and-bars-combinatorics)

but in that I could understand [what do they mean by](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910809/how-to-use-stars-and-bars-combinatorics) ways to divide the 6 letters A that are left in 4 parts. E.g. AA,A,,AAA. and after that also few things I cannot undersatnd .

Can anybody make it more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll explain A) for now

For there to be $4$ runs of $A$ and $4$ runs of be either it will be:

$$(A\dots A)(B\dots B)(A\dots A)\dots$$

or it will be

$$(B\dots B)(A\dots A)(B\dots B)\dots$$

Each of these runs will have *at least* one of their respective letters in it (*specifically not zero*) and may have some amount of extra of their respective letters in each.  Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4$ be the number of $a$'s in the first, second, third, and fourth runs respectively.  Similarly define $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4$.

We have the following system of equations:

$$\begin{cases} a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=10\\b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4=8\\1\leq a_i~~\forall i\\ 1\leq b_i~~\forall i\end{cases}$$

> A choice of beginning with A's and a choice of the solution $(a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4,b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4)=(3,1,3,3,4,2,1,1)$ for example will correspond to the arrangement $AAABBBBABBAAABAAAB$

The number of solutions to this is the product of the number of solutions to the systems $\begin{cases}a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4=10\\1\leq a_i~~\forall i\end{cases}$ and $\begin{cases}b_1+b_2+b_3+b_4=8\\1\leq b_i~~\forall i\end{cases}$

Solve the number of solutions to each of these sub-problems via stars and bars.  For the first system involving $a$'s, there are $\binom{9}{3}$ solutions.  To the system with the $b$'s there are $\binom{7}{3}$ solutions.

Choosing whether it is an $A$ at the beginning or a $B$ at the beginning, choosing which solution to the system with $A$'s, then choosing which solution to the system with $B$'s, and applying multiplication principle, we have then a final total of:

$$2\cdot \binom{9}{3}\cdot \binom{7}{3}$$