# Calculate no of sequences with sum k, out of die toss n times, with die having m outcomes

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, dice

I am trying to calculate total no of sequences possible with given sum k, out of a die (with m outcomes), tossed n times.

I could go after each combination, but $m^n$ grows very large quickly, so want a faster way to generate this. For coin flip, I simply grabbed binomial coefficients of respective row from Pascal's triangle, but here I am stuck on how to proceed. Can you kindly help?

*Big picture*:I am trying to understand how underlying nature of combinations evolve into normal distribution both theoretically and statistically.

Below is when I throw dice with 3 outcomes (0,1,2), 2 times. I get $[1,2,3,2,1]$ as the frequency of sequence as you see on LHs of the diagram.

[image]

Below is when I throw dice with 3 outcomes (0,1,2), 3 times. I get $[1,3,6,7,6,3,1]$ as frequency of sequence.

[image]

I have generated these, by directly generating all possible combinations and counting. When n is large, computing time is exponentially large. So I want a formula shortcut to come up with these frequency values pro grammatically. This is why above question.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553960/extended-stars-and-bars-problemwhere-the-upper-limit-of-the-variable-is-bounded) is a discussion of a related problem.

Comment: checked it, could not relate directly. can you please transform that to this problem?

Comment: $a_i$ is the value of the $i^{th}$ die (or one less than that).  Your problem is the case where all the $r_i$ are equal.   Specifically, if you are dealing with ordinary dice, all of your $r_i$ are $6$.  The fact that your rolls are all at least $1$ is not a significant difference, as you can just subtract $n$ from the total and remove that constraint.

Comment: Worth noting:  the first answer specifically addresses the case where all the $r_i$ are equal.

Comment: Please check if my inference is correct. Suppose I have a die with 3 outcomes (say 0,1,2). I flip it 2 times.  Let X be sum of outcomes. I want to calculate $X_2$, that is, how many outcomes where sum is 2. So, $a_1 + a_2 + a_3 = 2$. If so, we need to solve $(1+X+X^2+X^3)^2 = \dfrac {(1-X^4)^2}{(1-X)^2}$?

Comment: No.  The sum on the left should end at $X^2$.  Might be worth noting that, in this specific  case, you could just use standard Stars and Bars since the cap is non-restrictive.

Comment: So it is, $(1+X+X^2)^2 = \dfrac {(1-X^3)^2}{(1-X)^2}$. I will explore Stars and Bars., however how do I solve above equation anyway generically? I am not able to derive further to summation like in that link.

Comment: As per Stars and bars [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910809/how-to-use-stars-and-bars), I should solve for my problem $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 2$, so n=2, k =3, so answer should be $\binom {1}{2}$ which would result in  negative/complex values? I am missing something.

Comment: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) is a simple to follow discussion of Stars and Bars.

Comment: I have updated my question with specific underlying background requirement why I want as well. Please check. I will check wiki and revert.

Comment: I tried theorem two also (non negative integers). For die with 2 flips, 3 outcomes, sum needed as 3, it should be $x_1 + x_2 = 3$, so $\binom {n+1}{k-1} = \binom {4}{1} = 4$ But as you can see in my figures above, for $X_k = 3$, the answer should be 2. which are (1,2), (2,1).

Comment: Not following.  If the possible outcomes are $\{0,1,2\}$ and you want a sum of $3$ then the cap is restrictive, since combinations like $(0,3)$ are not allowed.

Comment: In general, details matter.  The formulas given in the wiki article are correct.  If you are getting different answers it is either because you are asking a different question or because there has been an algebraic error.

Comment: yeah I am not saying wiki is wrong, but trying to figure out where I am making mistake.

Comment: Die with 2 flips, 3 outcomes {0,1,2}, there would be only one sum of 4 which is (2,2). Die with 2 flips, 3 outcomes {0,1,2} there would be only 2 sums of 3 which are (1,2),(2,1). How do I derive this using stars and bars. I am some where making mistake in applying it I guess.

Comment: Once again, naive Stars and Bars is only useful if there is no cap. In your first test case, there was no cap (you were asking about a sum of $2$ so the cap of $2$ was already implied).  Therefore the method applies.  However, if you are asking for a sum of $3$ then the cap does apply so the method does not apply.

Comment: By cap you mean the limit? If so, in my case, the maximum sum possible out of all outcomes would be the cap. For eg, for die with 2 flips, 3 outcome {0,1,2}, the maximum sum possible is (2,2) = 4, so that is the cap. Kindly enlighten.

Comment: Enough.  I regret mentioning the standard method, as it has little relevance for the overall problem.  It is a powerful tool, but its power is limited here.  I suggest studying it further on your own.

Comment: I tried my best to explain :(