# Calculation of probability with arithmetic mean of random variables for a total of 3 times

Tags: probability, statistics

Thanks to @Ben W for his answer to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005667/calculation-of-probability-with-arithmetic-mean-of-the-sum-of-random-variables/3005804#3005804), now I can calculate and have 3 equal probabilities:

$P(X_1) = P(X_2) = P(X_3) \approx 0.000148646896$
with $X_1 = X_2 = X_3 = 1620$

Following up, once that the 4 people got 405 as the arithmetic mean of the number on their cards, then they repeat the drawing 2 more time (3 in total). So, I would like to calculate the probability that the arithmetic mean of the number on their cards is 405 for a total of 3 times.

How to make that?

---

Some explanation is welcome.

Comment: "*I would like to calculate the probability of the event that 'the above 3 probabilities are the same'*"  Uh.... I don't understand your question.  If you give as a hypothesis that $P(X_1)=P(X_2)=P(X_3)$... then the probability that they are equal is $1$... since you already told us that they are equal.  If things are equal then they are equal.  A tautology is a tautology...

Comment: You haven't defined what $X_1, X_2, X_3$ are.

Comment: $X_1 = X_2 = X_3 = 1620$

Comment: I get the impression that you don't yet have a good handle on how to use the stats notation here.  Maybe try explaining your question in plain English.

Comment: @BenW, I know because I'm not an expert in the matter. Please, see the updated question and suggest improvements if it is not sufficiently descriptive.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me.  Let me see if I can explain better.  Can you describe the *physical* situation?  Are there now twelve players, in three groups of four?  What event are you asking to compute the probability of?  Etc.

Comment: @BenW, once that the 4 people got 405 as the arithmetic mean of the number on their cards, then they repeat the drawing 2 more time (3 in total). So, I would like to know the probability that the arithmetic mean of the number on their cards is 405 for a total of 3 times. Is it more clear? BTW I'll also update the question.

Comment: Just multiply the probabilities together.  You have $0.000148646896^3\approx3.2844869e-12$

Comment: @BenW, please post your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: You can answer your own question.

Comment: I'd to reward merit.

Comment: "*I would like to know the probability that the arithmetic mean of the number on their cards is $405$ for a total of $3$ times*"...  So... you have $X_1,X_2,X_3$ are random variables describing the average of the cards drawn in the first, second, third rounds respectively.  You calculated in the previous question $Pr(X_1=405)$ to be the value mentioned above and the same logic is used to find $Pr(X_2=405)$ and $Pr(X_3=405)$ to be the same.  You are not asking for the probability that the **probabilities** are the same... you are asking for the probability that the **outcomes** are all $405$.

Comment: There is a big difference between asking for the probability that $Pr(X_1=405)=Pr(X_2=405)=Pr(X_3=405)$ and asking for the probability $Pr(X_1=X_2=X_3=405)$.

Comment: Thank you but I don't really keep track nor care about my rep points.  I'm in it for the love of the game ; )

Comment: @JMoravitz, at the end everything should refer to number 405, in both the previous question where it is calculated the probability of the event that "the arithmetic mean of the number on the 4 cards is 405" and in this question where it is calculated the probability of the event that "the previous event repeated 2 more times (3 in total during the same observation) has again the arithmetic mean of the number on the 4 cards of 405".

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the probabilities together.

You have $0.000148646896^3 ≈ 3.2844869e-12$

Credit @Ben W