# Find the number of n-digit numbers

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of n-digit numbers whose sum of the digits is 11.

How do I go about approaching this question, using P.I.E?

This is what I tried.

n = 11, when  1 + 1 + 1 + ...  + 1
n = 2 when  5 + 6

Comment: @DonThousand  This is not a duplicate since no digit may exceed $9$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just [stars and bars](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910809/how-to-use-stars-and-bars) over the digits of the $n$-digit number, under the condition that the highest digit is non-zero.

So, the question is equivalent to asking how many ways are there to pick non-negative solutions to $$x_1+x_2+...+x_n=10$$To which the answer is $$n+9\choose 10$$

The issue is that we need to ensure that $x_1<9$, $x_2,...,x_n<10$. So, that is a total of $2n-1$ cases to remove. So our final answer is $$\color{red}{{n+9\choose10}-2n+1}$$

Comment: I get that the n + 9 comes from n + 10 - 1, but where does the 10 come from? Using stars and bars shouldn't it be $$ {10 + n -1 \choose n -1}$$

Comment: hilh: ${n\choose k}={n\choose n-k}$, Don: I think you are missing that $x_n$ is a digit, so $x_n<10$. Also, it is $11$ not $10$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be n - 1? Not 2n - 1 because there's a total of n numbers?

Comment: @hilh There are $n$ cases where one of them is non-zero and the rest are $0$. But, there are $n-1$ cases where the first one is $9$ and one of the others is $1$, and the rest $0$.

Comment: So the final answer should be $$ {n + 10 \choose 11} - 2n + 1$$. Since it's 11 not 10

Comment: No, @farruhota was incorrect. The first digit has to be at least $1$, so we can only allocate $10$.

Comment: Originally: $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=11, 1\le x_1\le 9,0\le x_i\le 9,2\le i\le n$.

Comment: @farruhota I made $x_1=$ the highest digit $-1$.