# Find the coefficient of $x^{31}$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots)^k$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, generating-functions

> Find the coefficient of $x^{31}$ in $(1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots)^k$, where $k$ is a natural number

***Background***: I have to use generating functions to do this

I have thought about using the product rule, defining $f(x)=1+x+x^2+x^3+\ldots$ and $g(x)=(f(x))^k$ but this doesn't seem too useful since I dont know the value of $k$, and even if I knew it, if it were a large number the process would be very tedious. Could someone help me please?

Comment: Maybe you can use that $f(x)=\frac 1 {1-x}$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n=\frac1{1-x}\;,$$

you’re interested in the coefficient of $x^{31}$ in

$$\frac1{(1-x)^k}=\sum_{n\ge 0}\binom{n+k-1}nx^n\;,\tag{1}$$

which is $\binom{30+k}{31}$. $(1)$ is a standard result easily proved by induction on $k$.

Comment: Perhaps it is worth mentioning that $$ \binom {n+k-1} n x^n = \binom{-k} {\phantom{-}n}(-x)^n, $$ so that this identity is a binomial theorem. $\qquad$

Comment: Your final answer is $\begin{pmatrix} 30+k \\ 31 \end{pmatrix}$ but shouldn't it be $\begin{pmatrix} 30+k \\ k \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: @fdez: No: $n=31$, so $n+k-1=30+k$, and the lower number is $n=31$. Of course $$\binom{30+k}{31}=\binom{30+k}{(30+k)-31}=\binom{30+k}{k-1}\;,$$ so you do have that alternative.

Answer (score 2):

As Brian's solution is algebraic, here is a combinatorial proof: Let $m$ be a non-negative integer and $k$ be a positive integer. Then the coefficient of $x^m$ in the expansion of $$(1+x+x^2+x^3 +\cdots)^k$$ is the number of weak $k$-compositions of $m.$ This is the number of ways in which $m$ indistinguishable balls can be placed into $k$ distinguishable boxes such that empty boxes are allowed. By the [sticks-and-stones method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)#Number_of_compositions), this number is $\binom{m+k-1}{k-1}.$ So the answer is $$\binom{30+k}{k-1}=\binom{30+k}{31}.$$

Comment: What's the difference between "non-negative" and "positive"? I think the first term does include the number $0$ and the second one doesn't, but I am not quite sure since English is not my mother tongue

Comment: @fdez Non-negative means zero is included. Positive means zero is not included. Your intuition is correct.

Answer (score 2):

If you imagine expanding the given product, all the terms that contribute to the coefficient of $x^{n}$ must come from exponents that sum up to $31$, so your coefficient will be the number of solutions $(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k)$ to the equation $$a_1+a_2+\dots+a_k=n,$$ where each $a_i$ is an integer in $[0,n]\cap\mathbb Z$. This is a classic problem in combinatorics sometimes known as the "Stars and Bars" problem, whose answer is $$\binom{n+k-1}{n}.$$
See [How to use stars and bars?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/910809/496634) for an explanation.