# Notation for General n-Simplex Number

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation, binomial-coefficients

I'm looking to see if there is a standard notation for the following other than Binomial coefficient notation...

The triangular numbers $1,3,6,10,15,21,...$ are notated as $T_n$ and represented as $\binom{n+1}{2}$

The tetrahedral numbers $1,4,10,20,35,56,...$ are notated (per Wikipedia) as $Te_n=\sum{T_n}$ and represented binomially as $\binom{n+2}{3}$

Then there are the 5-cell numbers $1,5,15,35,70,126,...$.  These would naturally be represented as $\sum{Te_n}$, but was wondering if there was any other representation of this family of sequences of higher order n-simplex numbers...

Comment: OEIS [uses the terminology](http://oeis.org/wiki/Simplicial_polytopic_numbers) "simplicial polytopic numbers".  It also lists a few formulas.  Not sure where your interest lies, either on the terminology or the formula expressions. "The $d^{th}$ column of Pascal's triangle gives the $d$-dimensional simplicial polytopic numbers, forming simplex polytopes."

Comment: I found what I am looking for...  thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already know, these [simplicial polytopic numbers](http://oeis.org/wiki/Simplicial_polytopic_numbers) are readily expressed as binomial coefficients.  The $n^{\text{th}}$ number in the sequence of $d$-dimensional simplex figurates is $\binom{n+d-1}{d}$, which is also called a *stars-and-bars* number as it also [arises in that context](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/910820/3111).

Some authors employ an *emphasized* variant of the binomial coefficient notation to mean this closely related expression.  For example the OeisWiki page linked above uses doubled parentheses:

$$ \left(\! \! \binom{n}{d} \! \! \right) := \binom{n+d-1}{d} $$

while the [WolframMathworld page](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multichoose.html) uses single **bold** parentheses for what it terms "multichoose". When I try to recreate these bolded delimiters with $\LaTeX$ here, the effect is rather too subtle:

$$ \mathbf{\bigg{(}} \genfrac {}{}{0pt}{}{n}{d} \mathbf{\bigg{)}} $$

Comment: Should it be $d^{\text{th}}$ number in the sequence of $n$-dimensional simplex, according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_simplex#Number_of_coefficients)?

Comment: @Dreamer: That is a good illustration of how the same values arise in varied contexts.  A better Wikipedia parallel is the [subsection on Figurate Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figurate_number#Triangular_numbers_and_their_analogs_in_higher_dimensions) that expresses triangular numbers and their higher dimensional analogs.  My terminology agrees with the OeisWiki page that I linked.