# Distributing 10 books to 5 schools

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, binomial-coefficients

The problem asks:

```
10 copies of a book are distributed in 5 schools.
1. In how many ways can these books be distributed among schools?
2. What if at least one book is assigned to each school?
```

What I'm thinking is "*I have 10 books to distribute in 5 schools, no matter how, so perhaps I can even give all the books to a single school*"
So my answer to the first question is $C'_{10,5}=C_{14,5}$.
For the second question I was thinking "*I have to give at least one book at school (so $C_{10,5}$), the rest (5) to any school, no matter how, so $C'_{5,5}$ my final answer is $C_{10,5} C'_{5,5}$*".
Actually,  I was wrong on both answers, the answers are: $$1)\ C_{14,10}\\2)\ C_{9,5}$$
Why?

Comment: What is your $C'$ notation - is this the [multiset coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset#Counting_multisets)? Note that the classes that are distinguishable (schools) drive the transitions, not the indistinguishable quantity (books).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the five schools by $1,2,3,4,5$ and let $x_1,\ldots,x_5$ be the number of books distributed to each school, respectively. Then we always have an equation: $$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5=10.$$ Our goal is to find the number of *non-negative* integer solutions under some specific conditions.

1. There is no restriction, so by the star-and-bars formula, the number of non-negative integer solutions is precisely $$\binom{10+5-1}{10}=\binom{14}{10}.$$
2. Now we have a restriction that $x_i\geq 1$ for $i=1,2,3,4,5$, but the star-and-bars formula only works for the restriction $x_i\geq 0$. Therefore, we define $y_i:=x_i-1$ for each $i$. Then the system becomes $$y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4+y_5=5,$$ where $y_i\geq 0$ for all $i$. Clearly, there is a one-to-one correspondence between the solution to $y_i$'s and the solution to $x_i$'s. By the star-and-bars formula, the number of non-negative integer solutions is $$\binom{5+5-1}{5}=\binom{9}{5}.$$

For the star-and-bars formula, you can check the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29).

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple combinatorics problem where, as there is no restriction on having at least 1 book per school or such we can just plug in this formula.

(n+r-1) Choose r , which in this case is 14 choose 5 which is 2002.

Now if you need at least 1 book per school, This means that we can control the distribution of 5 books in any order. So again buy the same formula we get 9 choose 5 which is 126.

This theorem can be proved by the stars and bars method ([Stars and bars method discription])[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910809/how-to-use-stars-and-bars). Please note that if your training for olympiads this theorem is bound to come in handy.