# Newton Binomial for number of integer solutions to $|x|+|y|+|z|=30$

Tags: combinatorics

Following my post here: [Newton Binomial to find $(x_1+x_2+x_3)(x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7)=77$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4072555/newton-binomial-to-find-x-1x-2x-3x-4x-5x-6x-7-77)

I would like to know the number of integer solutions to |x|+|y|+|z| = 30. Without the absolute value I get 32 choose 30 (496). With the absolutes, I get 3602 (by computer simulation) and I don't know why...

Comment: Title: "Neuton" should be "Newton".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula for the number of **positive** solutions to the equation
$$
x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k=n
$$
reads
$$
\binom {n-1}{k-1}.
$$
Therefore the number your are looking for is:
$$
2^3\binom{29}2+\binom312^2\binom{29}1+\binom322^1\binom{29}0=3602,
$$
where the terms count contributions with the number of zeros in the set $\{a,b,c\}$ being $0,1$ and $2$, respectively.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** Consider the equation
$$
a+b+c=30 
$$
with $0 \leq a,b,c$.

For each solution with $a,b,c \geq 1$ you get $8$ solutions $x= \pm a, y= \pm b, z=\pm c$ to your equation.

For each solution with exactly one of $a,b,c$ equals zero you get $4$ solutions to your equation.

For each solution with exactly one of $a,b,c$ equals zero you get $2$ solutions to your equation.

Comment: Thanks allot for your answer! Unfortunately I still can't figure out how to incorporate your hint :-(   Can you elaborate? Thanks

Comment: avi, after this you can use generating functions or stars and bars

Comment: @AviTal If $a,b,c \geq 1$ then set $a'=a-1,b'=b-1,c'=c-1$ and use stars and bars. If $a=0$ and $b,c >1$ you need to solve $b+c=30$ with $b \geq 1, c \geq 1$. AGain, set $b'=b-1, c'=c-2$ and solve via stars and bars..